# Merge 2 columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do the same as what I can do with my function: `df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio` but on the `Country` instead of the exactly same row only the first 2 keys because I can't change the language of the data. So I want to read only the 2 first keys of `Country`column instead of all keys of `Country`column

df_g:

```
Sitio,Country
Los Andes Online,HN - Honduras
Guarda14,US - Estados Unidos
Guarda14,PE - Peru
```

df_seg:

```
Sitio,Country,Precio
Los Andes Online,HN - Honduras,0.5
Guarda14,US - United States,2.1
```

What I need:

```
Sitio,Country,Bidfloor
Los Andes Online,HN - Honduras,0.5
Guarda14,US - United States,2.1
Guarda14,PE - Peru,NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need additional key for help the merge , I am using `cumcount` to distinguish the repeat value

```
df1.assign(key=df1.groupby('Sitio').cumcount()).\
  merge(df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('Sitio').cumcount()).
   drop('Country',1),
    how='left',
     on=['Sitio','key'])
Out[1491]: 
              Sitio              Country  key  Precio
0  Los Andes Online        HN - Honduras    0     0.5
1          Guarda14  US - Estados Unidos    0     2.1
2          Guarda14            PE - Peru    1     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add and drop a merge column and you are done:

```
df_seg['merge_col'] = df_seg.Country.apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])

df_g['merge_col'] = df_g.Country.apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
```

then do:

```
df = pd.merge(df_g, df_seg[['merge_col', 'Precio']], on='merge_col', how='left').drop('merge_col', 1)
```

returns

```
Sitio   Country Precio
0   Los Andes Online    HN - Honduras   0.5
1   Guarda14    US - Estados Unidos 2.1
2   Guarda14    PE - Peru   NaN
```

Comment: This will not given back the output

Comment: There I fixed it, sort of.

Comment: thanks bro, and if i have `df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Espacio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio`??